# SQLServer: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting.

[image: img]

Here is the snippet I am tying to run

```
USE [Warehouse_PCL]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RouteTable]    Script Date: 2/19/2018 2:27:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RouteTable](
            [BranchID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [StoreID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [WaveGroup] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Wave] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Aisle] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Lane] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_RouteTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
            [BranchID] ASC,
            [StoreID] ASC,
            [WaveGroup] ASC,
            [Wave] ASC,
            [Aisle] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I am unsure what is causing this, any thouhts? Let me know if there is any other information I can provide to help.

```
===================================

Cannot execute script.

===================================

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.SetScrollPosition(Int32 iBar, Int32 iFirstVisibleUnit)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VSTextEditorTabPage.Clear()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.DisplaySQLResultsControl.Clear()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.DisplaySQLResultsControl.PrepareForExecution(Boolean prepareForParse)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptAndResultsEditorControl.StandardPrepareBeforeExecute(QEStatusBarKnownStates newStatusBarState)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.SqlScriptEditorControl.StandardPrepareBeforeExecute(QEStatusBarKnownStates newStatusBarState)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptAndResultsEditorControl.OnExecScript(Object sender, EventArgs a)
```

Comment: The IDE is boned. No query throws a NRE. That's the application having problems. Reinstall.

Comment: What server version, and what SSMS version? This often happens when you try to connect an older version of SSMS to a newer version of SQL Server and it doesn't understand some of the server's responses.

Comment: Also, there are two icons to the bottom left of the error dialog. What's in them? Probably more information about the error that belongs in an [edit].

Comment: Updated question with more details.

Comment: Agree with Will, reinstall SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/7ph1ru/ssms_2014_express_impossible_error) suggests that the problem is related to the .NET Framework update [KB4055532](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055532/security-and-quality-rollup-for-net-framework-3-5-1-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-4). Try the workarounds suggested [here](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/53).